# Circular dependency on a factory pattern

Tags: typescript

Let's have the following pattern:

```
const mapping:Map<string,Type<A>>=new Map<string,Type<A>>([
  ["b",B],
  ["c",C]
])

abstract class A{
   var childrenTypes:string[];
   var children:A[];
   public setupChildren():void{
     this.children=this.childrenTypes.map(t=>mapping.get(t).new());
   }
}

class B extends A{}

class C extends A{}
```

This results in a circular dependency. Moving the setupChildren method as a static method in another class doesn't break the circular dependency.

LATER EDIT: the solution should work for an arbitrary number of classes extending A, placed in different files.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `mapping` declaration to the end?

```
abstract class A{
   childrenTypes: string[]; // not var
   children: A[]; // not var
   public setupChildren():void{
     // there's no method named "new".
     // you need ! to ignore the possibly-undefined return value of get(),
     // or you need to do a check for the get() result
     this.children=this.childrenTypes.map(t=> new (mapping.get(t)!));
   }
}

class B extends A{}

class C extends A{ }

// set mapping here    
let mapping: Map<string, Type<A>> = new Map<string, Type<A>>([
  ["b",B],
  ["c",C]
])
```

Now it compiles without anything being used before it's declared.  The reference to `mapping` inside the the definition of `setupChildren()` is not a problem because it never gets run before the value of `mapping` is set.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. It does help, but it only solves my *over*simplified example :D -- in real life, the B and C classes would be put in different files, so the order of evaluation would not be guaranteed. plus, it looks like webpack is detecting this kind of circularity regardless. Also, thanks for the "new" catch. In the actual code, I am building a dynamic Angular view based on various (nested) components, in a data driven layout. If the mapping returns nothing, a "default" component is rendered, with a "not found" message.

Comment: If you're getting errors in webpack or TypeScript, please put them in your question.  Without a [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, you probably won't get an answer that satisfies you.